# Why does windows keep resetting my proxy autoconfig location?

Tags: windows-7, proxy, autoproxy

I switch between two networks, each of which requires different autconfig settings. In order to simplify things, I merged their two pac files and pointed the LAN Settings to that file. Now, for some reason, when I connect to one of the networks it changes my LAN settings to point to that network's online pac file. This breaks the efficiency of using a combined file. What could be causing this, and how can I make it stop?

Comment: You've not given us much information about the networks, so no way anyone can give you a definitive answer, only guesses. My guess is, if it's a commercial network there might be a log on script or policy running which changes it. Therefore, you won't have control of it without permission from the administrator.

Comment: Is there other information I could give you which would help with a definitive answer?

Comment: First things first, before you spend much time on this, I'd suggest you find out if the network in question has a script running or other policies in place which are causing what you've described. If they are controlling it at log on, then there isn't much reason to continue this.